# Custom syntax highlighting in Atom

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

As a self-exercise, I developed a simple assembler-like language. I'd like to add syntax highlighting for this in Atom. I have command, comments, and literals highlighting correctly, but for some reason my variables don't highlight.

Here is an example of the language:

```
# comment
cmd $v 1234    # comment
mov $ $v
```

Where `$v` and `$` are variables, and `cmd` and `mov` are commands.

Here is my `.cson` for the highlighting:

```
'fileTypes': [
  'yasa'
]
'scopeName': 'source.yasa'
'name': 'yasa'
'patterns': [
  {
    'comment':'command'
    'match':'^[a-z]{3}'
    'name':'support.function.builtin.yasa'
  }
  {
    'comment':'variable'
    'match':'\$[a-z]?'
    'name':'variable.other.normal.yasa'
  }
  {
    'comment':'literal'
    'match':'[ 0-9]+'
    'name':'constant.numeric.yasa'
  }
  {
    'comment':'comment'
    'match': '#.*'
    'name':'comment.line.number-sign.yasa'
  }
]
```

Everything works fine except the `\$[a-z]?` in `variable`. As I understand it, this should match the character `$` literally, followed by 0 or 1 of any letter from `a` to `z`, which is what I need. Unfortunately there is not highlighting on the variables.

Comment: Huh. That worked. Know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[$][a-z]?` safely because inside a *character class*  (those regex constructs defined within square brackets `[...]`) special regex metacharacters (or sometimes called *magic characters*) do not have to be escaped.

Normally, `$` denotes the end of a string (or a line, it depends on the regex modifiers, and also its behavior differs among various regex flavors). Escaping it is done either with 1 slash or 2 slashes (depends on the environment). If you are unsure, the rule of thumb is to put it into a character class.